# Which Game of Thrones actors and actresses were at Kit and Rose's wedding?

Tags: game-of-thrones, fandom

Christopher Catesby (Kit) Harington married Rose Eleanor Arbuthnot-Leslie on 23 June 2018. The two were known for their on-screen (Jon Snow and Ygritte) and off-screen romance.

Which *Game of Thrones* actors and actresses were at Kit and Rose's wedding?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with SciFi. Also it's trivia. If allowed it will prompt "Which <insert show/movie> characters were present for <insert comicon venue> occasions"

Comment: @KharoBangdo it is in fact on-topic as "Fandom information" (listed in the help centre that you link to in your close reason)

Comment: @Edlothiad But _should_ it be on topic? I agree with KharoBangdo that it shouldn't.

Comment: Also -1 for obviously no research effort. There are tons of articles and videos out there dealing with exactly this topic.

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek that's an issue for meta. As far as I'm aware this counts as Fandom information.

Comment: @Edlothiad yes, you are right about fandom questions being on topic. My VTC was wrong & against current site policy.

Comment: I think your intentions are correct @KharoBangdo and it's probably a great point to bring up on meta. I don't think fandom information should pertain to things unrelated to the show. It should be about costumes etc, behind the scenes things, not the lives of actors. We aren't "Celeb Gossip.SE"

Comment: -1 For no research effort. Plus, I don't think it's an appropriate question. However, from the comments above it seems to be okay.

Answer (score 18):

Looking on a few different sites [this list](https://www.elle.com.au/celebrity/kit-harington-rose-leslie-game-of-thrones-wedding-guests-17873) seems to have everyone that attended. It wasn't a very extensive guest list, with only 10 fellow Game of Thrones actors attending, and a rather dull wedding since no deaths were reported either.

Emilia Clarke (Daenerys Targaryen).

[image: Emila Clarke walking down the road behind a car in a pink jacket and long dress with a white handbag on one arm]

Sophie Turner (Sansa Stark) and Maisie Williams (Arya Stark).

[image: Sophie and Maisie walk together, Sophie wears thigh high black boots and a red jacket/dress; Maisie wears a black jumpsuit]

Liam Cunningham (Davos Seaworth).

[image: Liam arrives in a traditional black suit with white shirt and green tie; he's also wearing black sunglasses]

Richard Madden (Robb Stark).

[image: Richard arrives with a traditional Scottish outfit; a green and blue kilt, black blaser, waistcoat and bow tie with a white shirt]

Peter Dinklage (Tyrion Lannister).

[image: Peter arrives in a dark blue suit with a lighter blue shirt and a grey tie; he waves at people unseen to the side of the picture]

Ben Crompton (Dolorous Edd).

[image: Ben arrives smiling in a traditional black and white suit; other guests can be seen arriving behind him]

Conleth Hill (Varys), John Bradley (Samwell Tarly) and Joe Dempsie (Gendry).

[image: The trio arrive together holding their cards and presents; Conleth is wearing a dark grey three piece suit with a white shirt and red patterned tie; John wears a black three piece suit with a white shirt and black tie and Joe wears a navy blue two piece suit with a light blue shirt and a navy tie; he also has a white pocket square]

Comment: **"a rather dull wedding since no deaths were reported"** Not sure the bride and groom would agree with the "rather dull" statement. :-)

Comment: @RichS They're Free Folk, so of course they'd agree!

Comment: It should be noted too, that Richard Madden (Robb Stark) came in a kilt, that bloody legend is #NorthAF!

Answer (score 9):

Based off of articles around the internet including this one from [Elle](https://www.elle.com/culture/celebrities/g21875979/kit-harington-rose-leslie-wedding-guests/?slide=1), and [Mashable](https://mashable.com/2018/06/23/kit-harington-rose-leslie-wedding-game-of-thrones-stars/#d2za1j9uZPqw), below is a list of actors and actresses, in no particular order (excluding Rose and Kit):
<sub>Click the names to open images of the actors/actresses</sub>

- [Liam Cunningham](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guBSW.jpg) (Davos Seaworth)
- [Emilia Clarke](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ei3T9.jpg) (Daenerys Targaryen)
- [Sophie Turner & Maisie Williams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlbNf.jpg) (Sansa & Arya Stark)
- [John Bradley, Joe Dempsie, and Ben Crompton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMUUV.jpg) (Samwell Tarly, Gendry, Edd Tollett)
- [Peter Dinklage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlmrM.jpg) (Tyrion Lannister)
- [Richard Madden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCn9F.jpg) (Robb Stark)
- [Conleth Hill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQmHj.jpg) (Varys)

Malin Akerman was also present.